# I cannot send ETH from my blockchain wallet

Tags: ether

Yesterday i have Transaction {Dropped & Replaced)
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfdca0e5c597f0a3f298afd5d56e939a8cefc10117df6b22d5342e1b6d5803caf
I saw it Replaced by TxHash:0x2e441fa6a1fd48119c79352275522673780f1bf920318f67c4722a311f70cae1 and Success. But til now i cannot send ETH from my blockchain wallet. It said Please wait until your previous transaction confirms.
Anyone can help me?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, the transaction is dropped and replaced. But other than that there is nothing out of place in your wallet. Mentioning the plugin or application you are using might give more insight into the problem.

These problems generally occur when:

1. One of the transaction is still pending.
2. The application got your wallet's nonce wrongly.

In most cases, sending a transaction with 0 ETH from your wallet to you wallet. This will cancel all the previously pending transaction and fix the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue.
I imported 12 char to imtoken mobile.